# What does the formula (CH2O)106(NH3)16H3PO4 represent?

Tags: chemical-biology, geochemistry

The molecular formula $\ce{(CH2O)106(NH3)16H3PO4}$  appears in the wikipedia entry for "[anoxic bodies of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anoxic_waters#Causes_and_effects)". A quick search suggests that it represents the product of photosynthesis, or the generic starting point for breakdown of organic matter in the nitrogen cycle, in particular the process of [denitrification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denitrification) of "organic matter". On page 271 of Ref. (1) it is suggested  that it represents the structure of "marine plankton". This formula seems relatively widespread in use. Exactly what "organic matter" is this supposed to represent?  What is its origin (who first proposed and perpetuated its use)?

**References**

1. Derek E. G. Briggs (Ed.), Peter R. Crowther (Ed.). Palaeobiology II (1st Ed.). Wiley-Blackwell (March 5, 2001).

Comment: It seems the original work denoting elemental ratio C:N:P = 106:16:1 (aka the Redfield ratio) as the most common among marine organics is Fleming, R. H., 1940. The composition of plankton and units for reporting populations and production. *Proc. Pacif. Sci. Congr.*, **1940**, Vol. 3, pp. 535-540. Unfortunately, I wasn't unable to find a full-text document yet.

Comment: Indeed from the context isn't a molecular formula but elemental ratios, so while the body of text poses a sensible question, "molecular formula" shall be removed from the title.

Comment: @Alchimista $\ce{CH2O}$,  $\ce{NH3}$,  and $\ce{H3PO4}$, are molecular formulas, suggesting they are building blocks of a larger structure. There must be a good reason why this "molecular-like formula" (if you prefer) and not an elemental ratio was reported.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redfield_ratio. See also respiration and nitrogen cycle.

Comment: @Alchimista Thanks! Yes, I saw the wikipedia page after following up on andselisk's helpful comment. I understand now that the formula was originally a ratio. If I'd known that it would have been unecessary to pose my question. And I still haven't read the explanation for why the ratio has been recast as a molecular formula, but have some leads.

Comment: Why not? That is a composition of matter, even a formula but not a molecular one.  You can do it. It can be done in Hill system or like that,  grouping likely to reflects some chemistry behind. For instance full combustion / respiration end in a block like CO2.

Comment: @Alchimista The point of the question is to figure out exactly where the formula comes from. Now that the source, a ratio, is clear, next step is to figure out why this particular formula was posited. Perhaps not extremely complicated, but, more complicated than combustion, methinks.

Comment: Even sulfur is also involved in the formula: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/96884/what-is-the-representation-for-sulfur-in-organic-matter. It's a good question. Probably, you can raise a bounty so the biochem expects here can have a go ;)